# Simple Form Validation for website (Javascript/Css/Html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple form:

```
<div class = "container">
<img src = "images/login.png">
<form name = "myForm">
<div class = "form-input">
<input type = "text" name = "username" id="username"
placeholder="Enter Username">
</div>
<div class = "form-input">
<input type = "password" name = "password" id="password"
placeholder="Enter Password">
</div>
<input type = "Submit" name = "Submit" value = "LOGIN" class = "login-form">
```

I'm trying JavaScript to make the form have simple validation to check if the username box is empty, but it won't work:

```
<script>  
function validateform(){  
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
if(x == null || x == ""){
alert("Please include a username");
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

What is wrong? Is it my syntax or naming? My form and name is correct use the variable, I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: you are not calling validateform() anywhere.
add this to your submit button: onclick="validateform();"

Comment: Check in the browser's console for errors

Comment: `<input type = "Submit" name = "Submit" value = "LOGIN" class = "login-form" onclick="validateform()" >`

Comment: @funkysoul I knew it was something so simple, thank you so much.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="username" required />`